# react-bootstrap and material ui look and feel

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui, react-bootstrap

In my web application, I'm using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/). ie, React components built on top of Bootstrap. I wanted to customize Bootstrap look and feel and I like Material design - so I searched a bit and I found [bootstrap-material-design](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design). I wonder if I can just use it, AFAIK it's 'just' an additional CSS file (?), and if it's going to play nicely with react-bootstrap. Have someone already tried that?

I would also be interested in similar projects. My goal is to keep my react-bootstrap code base, but still have a fancier UI. Otherwise I would have gone for Material UI.

Answer (score 0):

`bootstrap-material-design` just uses css classes where as `react-bootstrap` provides components.

Both uses classes to define styles. So what styles get applied boils down to class specificity. This might give you unexpected results. `react-bootstrap` styles are supposed to get more specificity because of nested css selectors.

You can use `material-ui` along with `react-bootstrap` and use components that suit your use case